# FadingActionBar with ActionBarCompat

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Is it possible to use the FadingActionBar (https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/FadingActionBar-Native) library in combination with the new ActionBarCompat library from Google?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a compatible version for FadingActionBar with the ActionBar Compat library. You can find it on https://github.com/felixWackernagel/FadingActionBar-Compat.